# Currently am coding an autoclicker, and am trying to constantly be changing the delay between clicks and am having trouble

Tags: python

I am currently coding an autoclicker for video games such as Minecraft acting as a legitimate person clicking. The issue I am currently running into is the delay, I cannot change the delay of it. I have already tried changing it real time as you can see in the on press function, but nothing has worked. I'd appreciated the help.

```
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode
from random import randint
import random
import decimal
import os
import keyboard

delay = random.choice([0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1])
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='[')
exit_key = KeyCode(char=']')
destroy_key = KeyCode(char=',')
ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        if click_thread != click_thread.running:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
        while key == start_stop_key:
            delay = eval(str(delay)) + operation + str(0.01)
     elif key == exit_key:
         click_thread.exit()
         listener.stop()
     if key == destroy_key:
         os.remove("test.txt")


 with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
     listener.join()
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval` there? Why not just pick a random value out of that list at the top again? Or just do math? And where is `operation` defined?

Comment: It's defined at the top.

Comment: It is not. `ops` is there, but no `operation`